# Android debug logging causes values to be stored in ArrayList to change

Tags: java, android, arrays, debugging, arraylist

I have an app that gets the position on screen of a click or move. All this code should do is normalise the position, to make it the same regardless of screen dimensions, and then add it to the array list. I've been debugging my app as the list was coming out as all 0's. However when i added the logging seen in the code below, the values are added correctly. without the log there the array has all 0's again. I honestly have no idea what could be causing this. How can logging change the values stored in the array?!

**Working code:**

```
                    counter++;
                    int xPercent, yPercent;

                    xPercent = 100 * xInput / maxX;
                    yPercent = 100 * yInput / maxY;

                    Log.d("after", xPercent + " and "+ yPercent);

                    sampleList.add(new Integer(counter).toString());
                    valenceList.add(new Integer(xPercent).toString());
                    arousalList.add(new Integer(yPercent).toString());
```

**Array Values:**

before logging:

```
Time in seconds,Arousal,Valence
1,0,0
2,0,0
3,0,0
4,0,0
5,0,0
6,0,0
7,0,0
8,0,0
9,0,0
10,0,0
```

After using logging:

```
Time in seconds,Arousal,Valence
1,59,29
2,49,27
3,37,25
4,27,28
5,25,33
6,25,40
7,29,45
8,37,49
9,57,53
```

Comment: That by itself would not cause the change. But clearly, you're not showing us all of the code - please do.

BTW, you can make your code more efficient by replacing 
`new Integer(myInt).toString()` with `Integer.toString(myInt)`

Comment: ok thanks, will make that change. Also i'm not sure what other code seems relevant here? there arent any other processes that go on that effect these variables. I've checked that the xPercent and yPercent are correct. and then they are recorded as 0 in the array unless there is that logging call in between?

Comment: This is one of the hardest things to learn about debugging - when absolutely everything looks ok, but it doesn't work, it means that at least one of your assumptions is wrong.

If you give us a small, self contained, compilable and executable sample that exhibits this behavior, we can try to find the problem. Absent that, we have nothing to work with.